# How do I get my dog out of my Minecraft boat

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I went fishing with my dog in a boat. He got stuck and I cant get him out. How do I get him back out? (Mcpe btw)

Comment: @Ginge Please don't answer in comments. Doing so removes removes from the community several options to judge, improve, and reward content.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get animals out of a boat is to break the boat by hitting it until it drops.